# Mysql Subtract SUM(Amount)DebitAccount from SUM(Amount)CreditAccount if DebitAccount == CreditAccount

Tags: mysql

Need to subtract credit totals from debit totals where credit and debit account number is the same. If a value exists only for debit account number, nothing to subtract, just need to get the value.

One table called 18_7_ChartOfAccounts looks like this:

```
ID | AccountNumber
-------------
1  | 2310
2  | 2380
```

Another table called 2_1_journal looks like this:

```
ID | Amount | DebitAccount | CreditAccount
-------------------------------------------
1  | 25.00  | 2310         | 2380
2  | 200.00 | 2310         | 2380
3  | 4.00   | 2380         | 2310
4  | 200.00 | 2380         | 2310
5  | 50.00  | 2380         | 2620
```

Based on advices created query that sums all values in column `Amount` where value in `DebitAccount` is the same.

Query does the following: `SUM(Amount)` FROM table `2_1_journal` WHERE `DebitAccount` in table `2_1_journal` is the same as `AccountNumber` in table `18_7_ChartOfAccounts`

```
$query_debit_beginning = "SELECT SUM(j.Amount), j.DebitAccount FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS c LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal AS j ON (c.AccountNumber = j.DebitAccount) group by j.DebitAccount";
```

Do not understand how subtrac one sum from other.

Need to get output like this

Account number is 2310, Value is 21.00 (25+200-4-200)

Account number is 2380, Value is 29.00 (4+200+50-25-200)

Account number is 2620, Value is -50.00 (0(DebitAccount turnover) - 50(CreditAccount turnover))

Query should be the following:

(`SUM(Amount)` FROM table `2_1_journal` WHERE `DebitAccount` in table `2_1_journal` is the same as `AccountNumber` in table `18_7_ChartOfAccounts`)

then

`SUM(Amount)` FROM table `2_1_journal` WHERE `CreditAccount` in table `2_1_journal` is the same as `AccountNumber` in table `18_7_ChartOfAccounts`

then

if `DebitAccount` is equal to `CreditAccount`, subtract `SUM(Amount)`DebitAccount from `SUM(Amount)`CreditAccount

No idea how to create such query. Please, advice.

Based on advises tried to add condition for select.
Here is with modifications. Is the code correct? Tried and appears that works as necessary

```
SELECT
a.AccountNumber, 
IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount

FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS a

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    DebitAccount, RecordYear,
    SUM( Amount ) AS Amount
FROM 2_1_journal WHERE RecordYear = 2013
GROUP BY DebitAccount
) d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    CreditAccount, RecordYear,
    SUM( Amount ) AS Amount
FROM 2_1_journal WHERE RecordYear = 2013
GROUP BY CreditAccount
) c ON (a.AccountNumber = c.CreditAccount)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.AccountNumber,
    IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount

FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS a

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        DebitAccount,
        SUM( Amount ) AS Amount
    FROM 2_1_journal
    GROUP BY DebitAccount
) d ON a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        CreditAccount,
        SUM( Amount ) AS Amount
    FROM 2_1_journal
    GROUP BY CreditAccount
) c ON a.AccountNumber = d.CreditAccount
```

Comment: Seems that instead of Amount the code do calculations with Accounts. I get  `[AccountNumber] => 2310 [Amount] => 0 [AccountNumber] => 2380 [Amount] => 0 [AccountNumber] => 2620 [Amount] => -2620`

Comment: My bad. Updated query. SELECT should SUM 'amount' field, not CreditAccount or DebitAccount.

Comment: Now in Mysql is only one row `1  | 25.00  | 2310         | 2380` and output is `[AccountNumber] => 2310 [Amount] => 50.00` and `[AccountNumber] => 2380   [Amount] => -75.00` Appears that it somehow sums 2 times one value...

Comment: Yes, now exactly the same values as expected

Comment: only instead of `c ON a.AccountNumber = d.CreditAccount` need `c ON a.AccountNumber = c.CreditAccount` last `d.` to `.c`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it (not tested)

```
SELECT a.ID, a.AccountNumber, IFNULL( CreditAmount, 0 ) - IFNULL( DebitAmount, 0 ) 
FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DebitAccount AS AccountNo, SUM(Amount) AS DebitAmount FROM 2_1_journal GROUP BY DebitAccount) b ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CreditAccount AS AccountNo, SUM(Amount) AS CreditAmount FROM 2_1_journal GROUP BY CreditAccount) c ON a.AccountNumber = c.AccountNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN 2_1_journal c ON a.AccountNumber = c.CreditAccount
GROUP BY a.ID, a.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Get error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.ID' in 'field list'` Sorry, seems my mistake. Will check my column names. Have got array with values. Seems the code works. Will check again

Comment: a.ID should not be included in GROUP BY. Posted similar answer, but with GROUP BY for AccountNumber only.

Comment: It should be included in the GROUP BY if it is being output (as it is here). MySQL does allow it to not be included, but most flavours of SQL would just error if it were not included. Generally leaving out returned fields from the GROUP BY is not a good habit to get into.

Comment: Look at the data example. The first two rows would not add up together for Credit, because their IDs are not the same. And neither will the last 3 rows add up together for Debit, because their IDs are not the same.

Comment: Hmm, yes compared results summing in Excel with results of the script. Results for particular account are not the same...

Comment: @walterquez - There id values ARE the same as it is the ID from the 18_7_ChartOfAccounts table. Nothing is mentioning the b.ID which differs. Spotted the issue with my query and fixed it.